# proof that this sequence converge if the other converge

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> If $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are two real sequences such that $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $e^{a_n}=a_n+e^{b_n}$
>
> - prove that  $a_n>0\Rightarrow b_n>0$
> - prove that if $a_n>0\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_n$ converges then $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{b_n}{a_n}$ converges

For the first I thought

$$\begin{align}
e^{b_n}&=e^{a_n}-a_n\\
b_n&=\ln(e^{a_n}-a_n)
\end{align}$$

Taking $f(x)=\ln(e^x-x)$ we have that $f(0)=0$ and $f'(x)=\frac{e^x-1}{e^x-x}$ since for $x>0$ we have $e^x>x$ and $e^x>1$ then $f'(x)>0$ then $f(x)$ is increasing on $(0,+\infty)$, then $f(x)>f(0)=0$, then

$$b_n=f(a_n)>0,a_n>0$$

since $a_n>0,b_n>0$ and by $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_n$ converges then $a_n\to0$ and $e^{a_n}-1\to0$ and $e^{a_n}-1-a_n\to0$

with the hint we have $e^{a_n}-1-a_n\sim\frac{a_n^2}{2}$ and $\ln(1+a_n)\sim a_n$ then for some constant $N\in\mathbb{N}$

$$\begin{align}
\sum\limits_{n=N}^{+\infty}\frac{b_n}{a_n}&=\sum\limits_{n=N}^{+\infty}\frac{\ln(e^{a_n}-a_n)}{a_n}\\
&=\sum\limits_{n=N}^{+\infty}\frac{\ln[1+(e^{a_n}-1-a_n)]}{a_n}\\
&\approx\sum\limits_{n=N}^{+\infty}\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{a_n^2}{2}\right)}{a_n}\\
&\approx\sum\limits_{n=N}^{+\infty}\frac{a_n^2}{2a_n}=\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n=N}^{+\infty}a_n
\end{align}$$

then $\sum\limits_{n=N}^{+\infty}\frac{b_n}{a_n}$ converges wich imply that $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{b_n}{a_n}$ converges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $a_n>0$, $b_n>0$, and since $\sum a_n$ converges, $a_n$ and $e^{a_n}-1$ converge to $0$. Then
$$
b_n=\ln(e^{a_n}-a_n)=\ln(1+(e^{a_n}-1-a_n)).
$$
Nowe use that $e^x-1-x\sim x^2/2$ and $\ln(1+x)\sim x$ as $x\to0$.